# gnuradio c++ connect self() throw bad_weak_ptr

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I want to invoke some code in my constructor

```
connect(self() , 0 , filter , 0);
connect(filter , 0 , self() , 0);
```

But I get exception

Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'

I do next

```
my_filter::sptr
my_filter::make(unsigned int interpolation,
            unsigned int decimation) {
auto ptr = gnuradio::get_initial_sptr(new my_filter
                     (interpolation, decimation));
ptr->wire();

return ptr;
```

}

And method wire

```
void my_filter::wire() {
connect(self(),    0, resampler,  0);
connect(resampler, 0, self(),     0);
 }
```

But I get error

```
Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  sptr_magic: invalid pointer!
 what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
```

How I can improve this?

Comment: We'd need a [mcve] but presumably at the point you call `self()` whatever object `self()` is contained in isn't currently owned by a `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

[Read when this exception is thrown](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/bad_weak_ptr):

> std::bad_weak_ptr is the type of the object thrown as exceptions by
>   the constructors of std::shared_ptr that take std::weak_ptr as the
>   argument, when the std::weak_ptr refers to an already deleted object.

Most probably your `self()` is just invoking `shared_from_this()` and there is no `shared_ptr` pointing to current object, since you are in construction time, so `shared_from_this()` must throw an exception.

Two fix it use pattern two step initialization.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<YourCalsss> YourCalsss::Create() // static method
{
    auto result = std::tr1::shared_ptr<YourCalsss>(new YourCalsss);
    result->init(); // inside that you will do a connect
    return result;
}
```

PS. I'm assuming you are using C++03 with `tr1` since error information provides this clue.

Comment: In gnuradio use make() method

Comment: class block : virtual public gr::hier_block2 {

Comment: public: typedef boost::shared_ptr<block> sptr;
  static sptr make();
 };